# Run bash commands on Linux server from Windows 10 batch file

Tags: bash, command-line

I am connecting to a remote Linux server through ssh.
I would like to run a .bat file on my computer to connect to the server, and once on the server, give bash instructions to the server, exit the server, and then run more command line instructions.
How can I do this ?
Also, is there a "paste" command to automatically paste the server's password ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: use ssh keys instead of password -- https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=use+ssh+key+instead+of+password&ia=web

Comment: Or sshpass, or ssh-agent.